# Decrypting the HTTP Live Streaming content

Tags: iphone, encryption, aes, http-live-streaming

I am trying to decrypt the AES 128 bit Video stream from Iphone captured on Wireshark. I have found the KEY files within the bin file mentioned in the m3u8 files on the wireshark traffic but i am not able to find how to decrypt that video data using these keys.

As per specs, IV will be the sequence number, AES will be 128 bit with CBC mode.

When I use the given key and IV to decrypt the TS captured using the OpenSSL, it fails and returns the Bad Decrypt error.

When i try to use a tool kpbe based on Bouncy Castle API, it returns the error as pad block corrupted. SO, i am completely stuck in this.

Do anyone knows about any library in c# which can help me in decoding this AES-128 bit encryption of data.

Or is there any way that i can validate that the data i have captured is correctly encrypted(which i think is correct).

Any sort of help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are assuming rather much about the knowledge of this forum, please provide more information about the used protocols, and (e.g.) if you have tried any C# libs already... Without that, you might not get an answer.

Comment: OK, i have extracted the data form the HTTP Live streaming. Extracted the TS, the Key file sand got he seq. number form the m3u8.

ALready tried using OpenSSl using the AEs-CBC mode with VI as the sequence number and the Key extracted. 

Also tried using the BouncyCastle based tool kpbe but the API return the error as pad block corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the OPenSSL library and then finally able to decrypt the content.

Comment: Could you show more detail? A user asked about it (in an answer that was naturally deleted due to lack of rep). Thanks